# Nested loop with 'if' statements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, if-statement, nested-loops

I am trying to loop through an array of options, and check each option to see if it matches a different option within a different array. If the two options match, do one thing, if they don't match, do another thing.

I have 3^2 available options, and it runs through nine times. It goes `(true, false, false)`, `(false, true, false)`, `(false, false, true)`, which isn't ideal. Instead, I'd like to see something along the lines of: `(true)`, `(false)`, `(true)`.

It sits in my frontend in an erb file. I realize that there shouldn't be logic there, and am happy for refactoring suggestions but did plan on moving it out after I figured out how to make the loop work.

Frontend Code:

```
<% @available_sites.each do |available_site| %>
  <% @sites.each do |site| %>
    <% if site.review_site == available_site.name %>
      <div class="site-row columns">
        <div class="column col-4 col-md-10 col-mx-auto">
          <div class="site-tile">
            <a href="<%= site.direct_review_url %>" style="background-image: url(<%= image_path("review_site_logos/#{site.review_site}.png")%>); background-size: cover;"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column col-4 col-md-10 col-mx-auto">
          <span>Average Rating: <%= site.average_rating %></span>
          <span>Review Site: <a href="<%= site.direct_review_url %>"><%= site.review_site %></a></span>

        </div>
        <div class="column col-4 col-md-10 col-mx-auto is-flex-centered request-row-buttons">
          <%= link_to 'Show', [site.location, site] %>
          <%= link_to 'Edit', [:edit, site.location, site] %>
          <%= link_to 'Destroy', [site.location, site], method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% elsif site.review_site != available_site.name %>
      <div class="site-row columns">
        <div class="column col-4 col-md-10 col-mx-auto">
          <div class="site-tile">
            <a href="<%= available_site.link_to_info %>" style="background-image: url(<%= image_path("review_site_logos/#{available_site.name}.png")%>); background-size: cover;"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column col-4 col-md-10 col-mx-auto">
          <span>Sign Up for <%= available_site.name %> Business Page: <%= available_site.link_to_signup %></span>
          <span>Review Site: <a href="<%= site.direct_review_url %>"><%= site.review_site %></a></span>

        </div>
        <div class="column col-4 col-md-10 col-mx-auto is-flex-centered">
          <%= link_to "Add #{available_site.name} to Review App", new_location_site_path(review_site: "#{available_site.name}"), class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Relevant Controller Code `sites_controller.rb` - policy_scope is for authorization:

```
def index
    @sites = policy_scope(@location.sites)
    @available_sites = AvailableSite.all
  end
```

Relevent Schema Code

```
create_table "sites", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "location_id"
    t.string "review_site"
    t.string "direct_review_url"
    t.string "place_id"
    t.decimal "average_rating"
    t.jsonb "extra_data", default: {}, null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "rating_count"
    t.index ["extra_data"], name: "index_sites_on_extra_data", using: :gin
    t.index ["location_id"], name: "index_sites_on_location_id"
  end
create_table "available_sites", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "link_to_info"
    t.string "link_to_signup"
    t.string "base_review_url"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["name"], name: "index_available_sites_on_name"
  end
```

I'm looking for help/a new direction on handling nested loops.

Comment: BTW, you don't need to use an `elsif` here, just an `else`.  You've already established that the names are not equal, so you don't have to check again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to make sure we're on the same page, I'm going to restate your problem:

You have a list of `AvailableSite`s and you want to display different information depending on if you have a visible `Site` for it.

If that's accurate, you'll want to use `find`.  Something like:

```
<% @available_sites.each do |available_site| %>
  <% site = @sites.find { |s| s.review_site == available_site.name } %>

  <% if site.present? %>
    <%# view fragment when you have a site %>
  <% else %>
    <%# view fragment when you don't have a site %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This will only output one set of elements per `AvailableSite`.

Comment: I spent the whole day on this, and couldn't figure it out. Thanks so much for your help on it!

Answer (score 1):

First, let's make it easier to parse and maintain by moving the two view partials into actual partial files. That way we have simply

```
<% @available_sites.each do |available_site| %>
  <% @sites.each do |site| %>
    <% if site.review_site == available_site.name %>
       <% render partial: "sites/site_available", locals: {site: site}>
    <% else %>
       <% render partial: "sites/site_unavailable", locals: {site: site}>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Much nicer to play around with!

Next, we don't need to render inside a nested loop; this is why you're getting 9 instead of 3 renderings. You need one outer loop over `@sites`. In each loop, it will (1) check availability, (2) render. That will look more like

```
<% @sites.each do |site| %>
  <% if site_available?(@site, @available_sites) %>
     <% render partial: "sites/site_available", locals: {site: site}>
  <% else %>
     <% render partial: "sites/site_unavailable", locals: {site: site}>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

where you have lots of options for what to actually do for, or instead of, `site_available?`, including:

1. Define it as a helper method, view code is exactly as above. Not my recommended approach, but it'll get the job done.
2. Use `@available_sites.map(&:name).include?(@site.name)`. Now it's more obvious that this is a loop (`include?` will loop), but that the render is happening outside this loop. Somewhat inefficient, but so is `AvailableSite.all` so could be fine for now :-)
3. Use a presenter: this is just a simple Ruby class that will take a `site` as an arg to the `initialize` method, and have additional logic and attrs (such as `@available`) that you can add without polluting the model, view, or controller. If this gets more complex I always advocate for starting here, but it may be a bit heavy-handed for right now.

---

```
class AvailableSitePresenter
  def new(site, available_sites)
    @site = site
    @available = available_sites.map(&:name).include?(@site.name)
  end

  def available?
    @available
  end
end
```